# Flutter StreamBuilder returned null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(   // irrelevant (?)
      value: DatabaseService().users,
      child: StreamBuilder<UserData>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          UserData userData = snapshot.data;
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return ProfileSetup();
          } else {
            return Scaffold(...
```

I want to check if the user has already set up his profile by checking if there is any data of the user in the Firestore Cloud. Otherwise the user gets send to the setup page. The problem is that when there is finally the user data in the cloud I get an error message and a red screen for half a second, but after that it continues as it's suppost to. Yet I don't understand why there is an error message.

> A build function returned null. The relevant error-causing widget was
>       StreamBuilder< UserData>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use connectionstates in streambuilders.
Try this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(   // irrelevant (?)
   value: DatabaseService().users,
   child: StreamBuilder<UserData>(
   stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
       UserData userData = snapshot.data;
       if (snapshot.hasData) {
       switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
       case ConnectionState.none:
                 return Text("No Connections");
       case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
       case ConnectionState.active:
       case ConnectionState.done:
         return snapshot.data.length > 0 ? ScaffoldPage() :ProfileSetup();
    default:
    break;
  }
  } 
          return Text("");
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the error. Also, (context, snapshot) is now underlined and says: This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement.
Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.

Comment: It means, you forgot to return widget for the builder function in some switch case @Vinzent

Comment: I've edited my answer try this now. Replace else condition with return Text("") or SizedBox()

Comment: I just realised that I had else { return null; } at the next StreamBuilder and that was why I got the error... thank's a lot anyway!

Comment: But using the connection state helped me now to get rid of another problem so thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using firestore in my new project and has same problem

In my case I wasn't getting any error but snapshot has no data so I did checked

```
if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('error ${snapshot.error}');
```

which helped me see what's error and it was because index wasn't enable